# Reference request for Leibniz rule and spectral sequences

Tags: homological-algebra, spectral-sequences, homology

Suppose $A_*$,$B_*$, and $C_*$ are chain complexes equipped with filtrations and a map $m:A_* \otimes B_* \to C_*$ respecting these filtrations. I am looking for a reference for the fact that the map $m$ will induce a map of filtered chain complex spectral sequences which satisfies the Leibniz rule.